# Change TextView colour and text in getView(...) in ListView adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, textview, android-adapter, classcastexception

I've searched for this and I could find exactly the answer I needed...

I have a navigation drawer `ListView`, and I when an item is clicked in the list, I want to be able to get the `TextView` from it, and change its background colour, text colour and make the text bold.

I've tried getting the `TextView` by doing the following;

```
adapter_navList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview_navdrawer, drawerItems) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        TextView item = (TextView) lv_navList.getItemAtPosition(i); 
        // Code to set the background, formatting, colour, etc.

        return view;
    }
};
lv_navList.setAdapter(adapter_navList);
```

However, I keep receiving the following error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

How would I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please use 
TextView item = (TextView) adapter_navList.getItemAtPosition(i).

Comment: @JayShah That doesn't work - Cannot resolve method 'getItemAtPosition(int)'.

Comment: Ok you have set arrayadapter to your listview.So your view is already textview.

You can use it like below::

((TextView)view).setTypeface(font);

((TextView)view).setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

Hope this help you..

Comment: @JayShah Thank you. Can you post your comment as an answer with explanation so I can accept it. Also, when I use the above, the second time I cast it, I am given a notice that it is redundant. How so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
adapter_navList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview_navdrawer, drawerItems) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        TextView mytextview=(TextView)view;
        mytextview.setTextColor(Color.BLUE); 
        mytextview.setTextSize(14);
        // Other code you may want to add

        return view;
    }
};
lv_navList.setAdapter(adapter_navList);
```